# Just installed the news extension and it crashed my Magento

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, performance, magento

Just installed the extension and it crashed my Magento site. I'm tried so but it not working Does anybody help what to do?

Comment: Can you provide the any more context? How about a backtrace or an example of code that fails?

Comment: clean cache! turn on logging! show me reports!

Answer (score 1):

Just open app->etc->modules-> and find the .xml file that you currently installed. and Open this xml file and edit

```
   <active>true</active>
    to 
   <active>false</active>
```

then clean cache from var->cache

hope this will recover your problem.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the temperory file "maintenance.flag" from root directory then your website will works back.

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

When an extension is being installed, a temporary file is created to set the magento website unavailable to the public. Check if the file is there and delete it. The file is named maintenance.flag and placed at the root folder of your magento installation.

Otherwise provide more information to get support but normally this place is for development problem and you should contact the author of the extension.